# ArangoDB Unattended Install in Vagrant Box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, arangodb, unattended-processing

Trying to setup an Unattended install of ArangoDB in a Vangrant Ubuntu box. I've followed the Unattended install instructions here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/operations/installation/linux/

However, this accounts for the password prompts, but not for the database upgrade and backup database files prompts. How does one go about silencing these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. Basically you need to use a the following command:

```
sudo debconf-get-selections | grep arangodb3
```

> If you get a "debconf-get-selections command not found error" then you need to install the debconf-utils package like so:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install -y debconf-utils
> ```

This will spit out a list like this:

```
arangodb3       arangodb3/password      password
arangodb3       arangodb3/password_again        password
arangodb3       arangodb3/backup        boolean false
arangodb3       arangodb3/password_mismatch     error
arangodb3       arangodb3/upgrade       boolean true
```

These are all the keys and types you'll need to set up an unattended install. When I say key and type I'm referring to:

```
  package/key      type
arangodb3/backup   boolean
```

In the example above the package is arangodb3, the key is backup, and the type is boolean. Then in your setup script you need to include it like so with your chosen values:

```
echo arangodb3 arangodb3/backup boolean false | debconf-set-selections
echo arangodb3 arangodb3/upgrade boolean true | debconf-set-selections
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to skinneejoe's answer, I had to set all the following selections to have the installation of version `3.3.19` run unattended:

```
RUN echo arangodb3 arangodb3/password string somepassword | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo arangodb3 arangodb3/password_again string somepassword | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo arangodb3 arangodb3/upgrade boolean true | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo arangodb3 arangodb3/storage_engine string 1 | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo arangodb3 arangodb3/backup boolean false | debconf-set-selections
```

The selections can be found in:  https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/master/Installation/debian/config.in